# If $\phi(z)$ conjugates $f^{-1}(z)$ to $\phi(z)/\lambda$ then it also conjugates $f(z)$ to $\lambda\phi(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-dynamics

On p.32 of Carleson/Gamelin *Complex dynamics* they show existence of a conjugation map for a repelling fixed point using the attracting case and I am trying convince myself of the statement "any map conjugating $f^{-1}(z)$ to $\xi/\lambda$ also conjugates $f(z)$ to $\lambda \xi$. "

Let $f(z)=z_0+\lambda(z-z_0)+\dots$ and $f^{-1}(z)=z_0+(z-z_0)/\lambda+\dots$.

**If $f^{-1}(\phi(z))=\phi(z)/\lambda$, why does it follow that $f(\phi(z))=\lambda\phi(z)$**

I get $f(\phi(z))=f(\lambda f^{-1}(\phi(z))$ but $f$ is not linear so I cannot say this equals $\lambda \phi(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've written your conjugation formula correctly. I think it should be
$$
\varphi(f^{-1}(z)) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\varphi(z).
$$

If we now write $w=f^{-1}(z)$,
then
$$
\varphi(w) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \varphi(f(w)) \: \text{ so } \: \varphi(f(w)) = \lambda \varphi(z).
$$
That is $\varphi$ conjugates $f(z)$ to $\lambda z$.

Comment: Of course, I feel embarrassed.